# There is really something like Objective C++?

Tags: c++, objective-c, cocoa, macos, objective-c++

I'm reading a [post](http://savoysoftware.com/blog/?p=114) about iPhone programming and I've noticed that the talk about Objective C++, the code shown in the post looks mainly like Objective-C but there also are several snippets in C++. Is it really possible to program Cocoa from C++?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

In addition to the other comments, I would add that Objective-C++ is not exactly the same as "program Cocoa from C++" because there is no C++ to Cocoa bridge involved.

In Objective-C++, you program the Cocoa API entirely with Objective-C objects/syntax. The Cocoa API remains unchanged, so you need to communicate with it in the same way (using Objective-C strings, Objective-C arrays and Objective-C objects).

The difference with Objective-C++, compared to plain Objective-C, is that you can *also* use C++ objects (containing Objective-C objects, contained by Objective-C objects or just along-side Objective-C objects).

Comment: Using it all the time - can be awkward at times but in general great for anything cross-platform, re-using existing business code, open source libraries, ...

Answer (score 9):

Yes.  Basically, Objective-C is a set of Smalltalk like object extensions to C.  Objective C++ is the result of applying those same extensions to C++.  This leaves you with a language with two different object models.

Apple's xcode development environment provides both an Objective-C and Objective-C++ compiler.

Comment: Is it just me or does the prospect of writing code in an environment with two different object models sound like a recipe for disaster to anyone else?

Comment: Maybe if another company was responsible for the development. Apple has a history of releasing quality software on time.

Answer (score 5):

[Using C++ With Objective-C](http://developer.apple.com/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/ObjectiveC/Articles/chapter_14_section_1.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP30001163-CH10-SW1)

Answer (score 1):

It's actually an easter egg in the Apple documentation to check whether anybody's reading - the same person wrote all of the WebScript documentation in the WO4 guides.

Yes, there is Objective-C++.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, there is.