# Using a C++ library in an Objective-C app?

Tags: c++, objective-c

I am planning on learning Objective-C to write an OS X application but it will depend on a library written in C++. Can I interface with C++ in an Objective-C app? I'm new to desktop development.

The C++ library will be used simply to analyze a file and return some data about that file. For example, in the libraries compiled example, in terminal you'd type

```
./xlsanalysis my_spreadsheet.xls
```

and it returns:

```
rows: 34
columns: 10
first row: "My Spreadsheet header"
```

Can I include this library directly into the Objective-C app or interface with it some how?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For this purpose, there is Objective-C++, e.g. Objective-C plus C++ (or vice versa). From Objective-C++ files (e.g. .mm files), you have full access to all C++ functionality. Be careful when casting types from C++ to Objective-C, e.g. you should convert a C++ `string` to a `NSString` by using something like `[NSString stringWithCString:cPlusPlusString.c_str()]` The other direction would be `string cPlusPlusString([objectiveCString cString])` (or `cStringUsingEncoding:`).

Answer (score 2):

Yes, you'll just need to switch any Obj-C files that include (directly or indirectly) C++ content into objective-c++.  Basically that just means changing the extension to `.mm` -- this will give you the ability to use C++ and Obj-C together in those files.

Answer (score 0):

Objective-C++.

http://www.google.com/search?q=%22objective-c%2B%2B%22
[How well is Objective-C++ supported?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/406753/how-well-is-objective-c-supported)
[There is really something like Objective C++?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/462924/there-is-really-something-like-objective-c)
[How much of C++ is supported in Objective-C++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/740989/how-much-of-c-is-supported-in-objective-c)